# The location of my country within Europe: 我先說一下我國在歐洲中的地理位置

Tags: translation, grammar, writing-critique

I started my essay with:

> 我先說一下我國在歐洲中的地理位置,⋯

Apparently, there are a lot of problems with this. It seems that the teacher thought my country was in Central Europe, since he changed 中 to 中部。I wanted to say:

> "I first talk about the geographical location of my country within Europe."

Should I have used 內 or 裡？

Comment: could also say: geographical position occupied by my country  我国在欧洲里占有的地理位置,

Comment: @user6065 Excellent suggestion. I found this in my dictionary and wanted to use it, but "occupy" has many meanings, one of them being military. I was afraid it meant that, so I didn't use 占有...

Comment: examining the relevant ones among 50 examples in jukuu for "占有  位置":there are 占有X位置: with X=
重要的：２１times,特殊：６,中心３,一席（的）２,优势,once: 适当的,突出的,前占有的,一个,最前,其应得的,非常清晰、鲜明、牢固的,那个我刚才一下子就放弃了的,自己的,which seems to show that the combination often refers to important or special positions

Comment: 歐洲中部is not as good as 中歐, which is used by 水巷孑蠻below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first try is a correct translation of the English you want to say. 内 or 里 are not as good as 中.

Better still, you can omit it, 我國在歐洲的地理位置. Here "in" is implied.

After your teacher's modification

我先說一下我國在 **歐洲中部** 的地理位置 = I first talk about the geographical location of my country in **Central** Europe. (Here 歐洲中部 means Central Europe and "in" is implied. Notice the change in sentence structure.)

user6065's suggestion 我国在欧洲里占有的地理位置 isn't good. If you say that, people will expect you to immediately follow that your country's location is strategically important (which may or may not be what you want, but certainly not reflected in your English expression).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is inappropriate to write that.

Because it carry different meaning when `中` used in this way.

`在歐洲中`

In mandarin, besides "central", it also carry the meaning of "among/within".

But even it is weird when translated to English : 
let's talk about my home country geographical location within Europe.

If English speaking people not going to write "home country", why complicate it with a foreign language. Even in many language, it is easier to say where you come from, then talk about country.  E.g.

我来自XX国。 对于XX国不大熟悉的人， 我先說一下XX国在歐洲的地理位置,⋯

Because non-European(even USA) rarely study Europe maps. Non-European have no idea which country make up of central European. So it is better to say Europe then narrow down to explicit location.

Answer (score 1):

```
I first talk about the geographical location of my country within Europe
```

the equivalent chinese is "not smooth". may i suggest:

我先說一下: 我的國家位於中歐 / 西歐

~ i first talk about: my country is located in central europe / western europe.

imo, "occupied" is a very bad term, to introduce geographic location; don't use this one.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you don't mind if I pepper up your English a bit first:

I first talk about the geographical location of my country within Europe

might be better so:

I would first like to talk about the geographical location of my country within Europe.

I would first like to talk about 我首先想谈谈一下

the geographical location of my country within Europe. 我国家在欧洲中的地理位置。

Comment: All corrections are welcome. English is my third language;) Mandarin my fourth.